# Delete Files after partitioned step processing

Tags: spring-batch

I have a scenario with multiple files to be processed with Spring Batch.

I implemented this with a master step and a partitioned slave step that process each file individual through Partitioner
It works fine but now I want to archive/delete successfully processed files.

I tried several ways but no success:

-in an afterStep method on slave step StepExecutionListener but the writer is holding lock on the file

-in a new step after master step, but I don't know how to get successfully processed file names, I guess this is an information that has to be shared with slave steps, also thread safety must be taken into consideration. This approach also has the disadvantage that it waits for all the slave steps to end.

Thanks in advance,
Adrian

Answer (score 1):

if you can accept to wait for all slave steps to end before starting file deletion you can reach the successfully processed file names with

```java
public class CustomTasklet implements Tasklet {

  @Override
  public RepeatStatus execute(final StepContribution contribution, final ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
    Collection<StepExecution> stepExecutions = chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getStepExecutions();
    for (StepExecution stepExecution : stepExecutions) {
      if (stepExecution.getExecutionContext().containsKey("fileName") 
          && ExitStatus.COMPLETED.equals(stepExecution.getExitStatus())) {

        String file = stepExecution.getExecutionContext().getString("fileName");
        // delete file

      }
    }
  }
}
```

if you customized the [MultiResourcePartitioner.keyName](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/MultiResourcePartitioner.html#setKeyName-java.lang.String-), you need to change the "fileName" above

Comment: Hi Michael,  Thank you for your answer, it works. I guess there is no solution to delete file after each slave step, so I have to accept that.